# Show images from Wordpress 3.5 gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, wordpress-3.5

First I create a gallery in a post (using the built-in Wordpress gallery).

Now, since I don't like how Wordpress shows the gallery (in the frontend), in the `single.php` page I want to retrieve the image IDs of that gallery, because I want to create a customized gallery using php code and a plugin like FancyBox.

I've tried many codes but no one works! I'm using Wordpress 3.5.1 with Bootstrap.

Comment: if you have tired code then please do paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how you do a custom gallery with the images attached to a post/page in WordPress. This is true about for WP 3.5 and older versions too.

```
<ul>
<?php $images = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID . ' &orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');
foreach( $images as $img_id => $img_r ) :
     $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'thumb', true );
     $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'full', true ); ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $full[0] ?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0] ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title( $img_id ) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $img_id ) ?>">
        </a>
     </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Add CSS classes to the HTML to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks but the script shows ALL the images uploaded in Media Library, not the ones attached to the single page...

Comment: I'm already using it inside the loop. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475491/showing-only-images-attached-to-a-page-and-not-all-attachments) please

Comment: I use this code myself and I actually extracted it from my project. Check if you have images attached to the post you are trying to show the gallery.

Other then that, it makes no sense not to work. Also, remove that little space before the & here: $post->ID . ' &...

Comment: Without the space before and after $post->ID it shows nothing! I don't understand what's wrong here

Comment: God, finally I understand what's wrong! Wordpress shows in the gallery ONLY the images that have been uploaded in the current post. If you add in the gallery an image that already was in media library, it will not be showed! Is this normal?? How can modify the script to shows all the images in the gallery?

Comment: Add this in the options: posts_per_page=-1. Don't forget the '&'.

Comment: It's the same... Wordpress shows only the images that have been uploaded in the current post

Comment: There is definitively something wrong with your code. Can you provide what you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look post/page gallery tip [***here***](https://coderwall.com/p/yc15ng?i=1&p=1&q=&t%5B%5D=%21%21mine&t%5B%5D=%21%21bookmarks).

It does more or less exactly what you are looking for and you can expand on the options.